# Closed form of $\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\zeta (n)^2 z^n$

Tags: definite-integrals, generating-functions, riemann-zeta, bessel-functions, harmonic-numbers

Recently, interesting problems related to sums over the zeta function reappeared, see e.g. [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684219/concerning-this-curious-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n122n-left-frac) or [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082045/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-left1-over-n-2-zeta2n-over-2n1-right/4688854#4688854).

In approaching these problems it is useful to study the generating sums. The generating sum of the zeta function is well known (see formula $(3)$ in [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4684219/concerning-this-curious-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frac2n122n-left-frac)):

$$g_1(z) :=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\zeta(n)z^n = - z H_{-z}\tag{1}$$

For ease of reference and because it is similar to what follows I repeat the derivation here:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\zeta(n)z^n & =\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } z^n \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{k^n}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{z^n}{k^n}\right)\\ 
& =\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{z^2}{k (k-z)}\\ 
&=-z \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-z}\right)=-z H_{-z}
\end{align}\tag{1a}$$

Here $H$ is the harmonic number.

It seems natural to ask for the generating sum of the square of the zeta function:

$$g_2(z) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\zeta(n)^2 z^n\tag{2}$$

My (unsuccessful) attempts are

(i) Harmonic number form

Using $\zeta(n) = \sum_{k \ge 1} k^{-n}$ gives, using $(1)$, recursively

$$\begin{align}g_{2,1}(z) & =\sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \zeta (n) \left(\frac{z}{k}\right)^n=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \zeta (n) \left(\frac{z}{k}\right)^n\\
& =\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } g_1\left(\frac{z}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\left( -\frac{z}{k}\right) H_{-\frac{z}{k}}\end{align}\tag{3}$$

(ii) Bessel form

Using

$$\zeta (n)=\frac{1}{\Gamma (n)}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{t^{n-1}}{e^t-1} dt\tag{4}$$

the kernel is

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma (n)^2} \int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }\frac{t^{n-1} u^{n-1} z^n}{\left(e^t-1\right) \left(e^u-1\right)}dudt\tag{5}$$

and the $n$-sum becomes

$$\begin{align}& \sum _{n=2}^{\infty } \frac{z^n \left(t^{n-1} u^{n-1}\right)}{\Gamma (n)^2 \left(e^t-1\right) \left(e^u-1\right)}\\
& =\frac{z \left(I_0\left(2 \sqrt{t} \sqrt{u} \sqrt{z}\right)-1\right)}{\left(e^t-1\right) \left(e^u-1\right)}
\end{align}\tag{6}$$

so that the generating sum has a representation of a double integral over a Bessel function:

$$g_{2,2}(z) = \int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }\frac{z \left(I_0\left(2 \sqrt{t} \sqrt{u} \sqrt{z}\right)-1\right)}{\left(e^t-1\right) \left(e^u-1\right)}dudt\tag{8}$$

Here I am stuck.

**Questions**

1. Can you do better and find $g_2(z)$?
2. Or, alternatively, can you find $g_2(\frac{1}{2})$ or $g_2(\frac{1}{4})$?

Comment: Using a similar process to your first attempt on the Dirichlet expansion of $\zeta^2(s)$, one can show that $g_2(z)$ admits the following Mittag-Leffler expansion:
$$g_2(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^2d(n)}{n(n−z)}$$
where $d(n)$ is the divisor function. The appearance of $d(n)$ doesn't inspire me with much confidence that there is a useful closed form.

Comment: @C-RAM very interesting (x^2 should read z^2, I think). Could you please elaborate, preferrably in a solution.

Comment: You are right; it should be $z^2$. Before I write anything, what sort of closed form are you looking for for $g_2(z)$? I did not think you were looking for another series like the one I provided, since the one you found is very similar (they both analytically continue the  function to $\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{N}$, and they are both derived in essentially the same way).

Comment: @C-RAM 1) Maybe it's easier to at look a fixed value as in my question 2.  Well, closed form in terms of the "usual suspects" of the family of $\Gamma, \zeta, \pi, \log, H(), ...$ 2) just a question concerning your formula: how is d(n) defined here?

Comment: That makes sense, though I highly doubt you're going to get anything better than this, your formulas, and the original power series. To give a quick elaboration here, $d(n)$ is the number of natural divisors of $n$. For example, $12$ has divisors $1,2,3,4,6,12$, so $d(12)=6$. Using the standard formula for a product of Dirichlet series, we see that $\zeta^2(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d(n)}{n^s}$, so we may write $$g_2(z)=\sum_{k=2}^\infty z^k\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{d(n)}{n^k}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty d(n)\sum_{k=2}^\infty(z/n)^k=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^2d(n)}{n(n-z)}$$

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer, since it neither provides a closed expression nor does it prove that there is none, but it is a continuation of reformulatinons which lead to perhaps interesting results.

**§1. The divisor function $d(n)$ appears naturally**

User C-RAM, in a comment, pointed out thet the square of the zeta function can be identified as the product of two Dirichlet series

$$\begin{align}
(f*g)(s)& = \sum_{j\ge 1} \frac{f(j)}{j^s}\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{g(k)}{k^s} \\
=& \sum_{j,k\ge 1}f(j) g(k) \frac{1}{(j k)^s}\overset{j k \to n}=\sum_{n \ge 1, k \ge 1\land k|n}f(n) g(\frac{n}{k}) \frac{1}{n^s}\end{align}\tag{s1} $$

specifically, for $g(k)=1$,

$$\begin{align}
(f*1)(s)& =\sum_{n \ge 1, k \ge 1\land k|n}f(n) (1) \frac{1}{n^s}=\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s} \sum_{k \ge 1\land k|n}(1) =\sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s} d(n)\end{align}\tag{s2} $$

where $d(n) = \sum_{k|n}1$ is the number of values of $k\ge 1$ which divide $n$, i.e. the number of divisors of $n$. Example $n=12$ has the 6 divisors $(1,2,3,4,6,12)$ hence $d(12)=6$.

The first few terms are $d(1..20) = \{1,2,2,3,2,4,2,4,3,4,2,6,2,4,4,5,2,6,2,6\}$

The sequence is listed in https://oeis.org/A000005. where also the generating function $\lambda(x)$ (called Lambert series) is given

$$\lambda(x)= \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{x^k}{1-x^k}=\sum_{k\ge 1}x^k \sum_{j\ge0} x^{k j}=\sum_{k\ge 1}\sum_{j\ge 1} x^{k j}\overset{j k\to n}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{j|n}  x^n=\sum_{n\ge 1}d(n)  x^n\tag{s3}$$

**§2. The Mittag-Leffler expansion of $g_m=\sum_{n \ge 2}\zeta(n)^m z^n$**

From $s2$ we have $\zeta(n)^2 = (1*1)(n) = \sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{ d(k)}{k^n}$

This leads to another representation of $g_2$ called Mittag-Leffler expansion

$$g_2(z):=\sum_{n \ge 2}\zeta(n)^2 z^n =\sum_{n \ge 2} z^n \sum_{k \ge 1}\frac {d(k)}{k^n}=\sum_{k\ge 1}d(k) \sum_{n\ge 2}(z/k)^n = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^2 d(k)}{k(k-z)}\tag{s4}$$

For the $m$-th power of $\zeta$ we obtain similarly

$$g_m(z) := \sum_{n \ge 2}\zeta(n)^m z^n=\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{z^2 d(m,k)}{k(k-z)}\tag{s5}$$

where, recursively,

$$d(m,k) = 
\left\{ 
 \begin{array}{ll} 
  1 & m=1 \\ 
  \sum_{j|k}d(m-1,j) & m\ge2 \\ 
 \end{array} 
\right. 
\tag{s6}$$

**§3. Attempt to calculate $g_2(1/2)$ using the Mittag-Leffler expansion**

From $(s4)$ we have

$$g_2(1/2) = \frac{1}{4}\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{d(k)}{k(k-\frac{1}{2})}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{d(k)}{k(2k-1)}\tag{s7}$$

Now it would be nice to have an explicit formula for $d(n)$. But we are in an even better position: we have its generating function $\lambda(x)$.

And we just need to generate the denominator which can be easily done observing that

$$\frac{1}{k(2k-1)} = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{p^2}\int_0^{p^2} \frac{x^k}{x} \, dx \, dp\tag{s8}$$

Hence we have to calculate the summand of $\lambda$, i.e.

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{p^2}\int_0^{p^2} \frac{x^k}{x(1-x^k)} \, dx \, dp\tag{s9}$$

The $x$-integral gives

$$\int_0^{p^2} \frac{x^k}{x \left(1-x^k\right)} \, dx=-\frac{\log \left(1-p^{2 k}\right)}{k}\tag{s10}$$

the remaning $p$-integral is then ... suspense ...

$$g_{2,3}=\int_0^1 -\frac{\log \left(1-p^{2 k}\right)}{k p^2} \, dp = -\frac{1}{k} H_{-\frac{1}{2 k}}\tag{s11}$$

and disappointment! We have (taking into account the temporarily suppressed factor $\frac{1}{2}$) just rediscovered the formula $(3)$ of the OP, hence $g_{2,3}=g_{2,1}$.

Little reward: at least one formula for the harmonic number popped up which was new to me and can be written as

$$H_{z} = -z \int_0^1 t^{z-1} \log (1-t) \, dt\tag{s12}$$

**§4. Micellaneous**

*The function q-Polygamma and the relation to $\lambda(x)$*

The [q-digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PolygammaFunction.html) is defined as

$$\psi_q(z) = -\log(1-q) + \log(q)\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{q^{n+z}}{1-q^{n+z}}\tag{s13}$$

Hence we have

$$\lambda(x) = \frac{1}{\log(x)}\left(\psi_q(z=1) +\log(1-x) \right)\tag{s14}$$

*3rd power of $\zeta$*

$d(3,n)$ is listet in https://oeis.org/A007425 as
A007425 d_3(n), or tau_3(n), the number of ordered factorizations of n as n = r s t.
G.f.: $\sum_{k>=1} d(k)*x^k/(1-x^k)$.

The generating function of $d(3,n)$ is given by

$$\sum_{n\ge 1} x^n d(3,n) = \sum_{k>=1} d(k) \frac{x^k}{1-x^k}$$